# Convert GCC/ATT style assembler to visual studio assembler?

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly

I'm trying to rewrite this snippet to work in visual studio, but I clearly don't understand how to use the purpose of the colons and the meaning of `__volatile__`,

may you offer some help :)?

```
__asm__ __volatile__ (
    "mov %0, %%edi\n"
    "xor %%eax, %%eax\n"
    "xor %%ecx, %%ecx\n"
    "dec %%ecx\n"
    "repne scasb\n"
    "sub %%ecx, %%eax\n"
    "dec %%eax\n"
:
: "m" (src)
: "memory", "%ecx", "%edi", "%eax");
```

Thanks!

Comment: [First hit on Google](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html). Are you essentially asking us to summarize that page?

Comment: No, I've tried by myself several ways but couldn't succeed, so I posted here the original code..

Comment: That looks much like `strlen()` or similar. Why do you bother and not use an ordinary loop or appropriate existing replacement?

Comment: Include your failed attempt and someone might point out where you went wrong and explain why.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed. The GCC and Visual Studio inline assemblers are completely different, so the question is not at all trivial.

Comment: You can only do it for x86, and you can't do it for x64. Microsoft does not support inline assembly for x64. See [Intrinsics and Inline Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbk4z78b.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two inline assemblers are completely different. The Visual Studio inline assembler is more primitive but easier to use. In VS:

- inline assembly language doesn't need to be enclosed in a string;
- instruction operands are in dest,src order;
- C/C++ variables are accessed as is;
- etc.

Your code doesn't have any output operators (after the first colon), so I don't see how it can have any effect. But suppose the `eax` register is to be saved in the `src` variable at the end. Then you want something like this:

```
char* src;
...
__asm {
    mov   edi,src
    xor   eax,eax
    xor   ecx,ecx
    dec   ecx
    repne scasb
    sub   eax,ecx
    dec   eax

    mov   src,eax    // save result
}
```

By the way, it looks non-optimal to me. All that business with `eax` could be done by `not ecx`, if I understand the code correctly:

```
__asm {
    mov   edi,src
    xor   al,al
    xor   ecx,ecx
    dec   ecx
    repne scasb
    not   ecx

    mov   src,ecx    // save result
}
```

Comment: Why did you drop XOR EAX,EAX ?

Comment: @user3144770: Why do you think it is necessary?

Comment: The SCASB instruction uses the AL register. So why should it not be properly initialized?

Answer (score 0):

> ... I don't understand ... the purpose of the colons ...

As Columbo pointed out in his comment, here is the relevant man page: [6.43.2 Extended Asm - Assembler Instructions with C Expression Operands](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html). The colons just separate tokens in the ASM block. They are similar to a semicolon terminating a C statement (or maybe, more correctly, the comma operator since they are related).

And to reiterate what the page is saying, the general format is:

```
asm (
        Instructions (Assembler Code)
        : Outputs (C variables modified by the instructions)
        : Inputs (C expressions read by the instructions)
        : Clobbers (Registers or other values changed by the instructions)
    )
```

Sometimes there won't be any token between the semicolons. For example, here's what a memory barrier looks like:

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ("" ::: "memory")
```

There's no assembler code, there's no C variables used as output, and there's no C expressions used as input. But the memory is listed as clobbered, so the compiler knows to ensure pending reads and writes have been completed before the next instruction is executed.

---

> ... I don't understand ... meaning of `__volatile__`

OK, so this is a can of worms because GCC and Visual Studio interpret the meaning of `volatile` differently (even though they use the same C language specification).

In GCC, the only reason to use `volatile` is when hardware can change memory. So I think the use of the qualifier `volatile` is an abuse in the example above (because it looks like the function is scanning for a `NULL` byte, and not performing memory mapped I/O).

You can find the relevant discussion on the GCC mailing list at [volatile shared memory](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2012-03/msg00242.html). Ian Lance Taylor, who provided the reply below, is one of the GCC devs:

> No, volatile can not address this.  This is not what the volatile
>   qualifier is for.  The volatile qualifier is designed for working with
>   memory mapped hardware.  It is not designed for multi-processor shared
>   memory.  If a program is not multi-processor safe, then adding
>   volatile will never make it multi-processor safe.

---

**EDIT**: As Tony pointed out below, [`volatile` is used to tame the optimizer](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Volatile) so that the ASM block is not removed during compilation.

---

Also note that you can convert the code to inline assembler for x86, but you can't do it for x64. Microsoft does not support inline assembly for x64. See [Intrinsics and Inline Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbk4z78b.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: `volatile` is necessary to stop the GCC compiler from optimising the whole asm-block away. It is irrelevant in Visual Studio, which would never dream of doing such a thing.

Comment: @Tony - that's interesting. I don't ever recall reading it in the GCC docs. Do you have a citation? (I might need to update that answer).

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Volatile. It's true that in most cases `volatile` is unnecessary, but unless you don't care whether your asm-block is optimised away or not, it is prudent to use it by default.